# How to Find the Image That is not Found on Ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm getting the error below when I reopen the application to see the image:

```
Could not initialize an instance of the type 'UIKit.UIImage': the native 'initWithContentsOfFile:' method returned nil
```

Is it possible to ignore this condition by setting

`MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure`

to false?

Below method is used to displaying the image

```
private async Task DisplayImageFromImageUrl()
{
 UIImage image;
 image = new UIImage(eventImageEntity.EventsImageUrl);
}
```

while executing the above code "image" showing "null" value.

Comment: Please add the code which is failing. Otherwise, it will be difficult to help you solve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to create an image from a URL, you need to use the following code:

```
                       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventImageEntity.EventsImageUrl.Trim()))
                        {
                            var url = new NSUrl(eventImageEntity.EventsImageUrl);
                            using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
                            {
                               UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
                            }
                        }
```

Otherwise you will just end up with a Null UIImage. That is what's causing your problem.

EDIT:

If you're trying to get the image from a resource location, then the following is necessary:

This assumes that it's from a specific user created folder:

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(@"Assets/NavigationBarAssets/HomePC.png")
```

OR

This assumes that the image is just say in the root of iOS 'Resources' folder

```
UIImage image = new UIImage("HomePC.png")
```

Comment: thanks @Digitalsa 1nt ,i am getting image from relative path while converting that path to UIImage it showing null value.

Comment: The code you listed in your OP suggests your trying to create an image from a URL (E.g. www.google.com/webenerds.png) if that's not the case and your doing it from a file path, or resource, then we ideally need to see the code your using for that, as it will be (Should be) different.

Comment: getting image from file path like:"Images/12234-1443-435-534535.png" format

Comment: @Prasanthi I've updated the answer to cover loading from the iOS resources folder, or a specific user created folder. Hopefully that will make more sense.

Comment: I am initializing UIImage image=new UIImage(eventImageEntity.EventsImageUrl) EventImageUrl contains image

Comment: it shows Could not initialize an instance of the type 'UIKit.UIImage': the native 'initWithContentsOfFile:' method returned nil

Comment: Are you sure that EventsImageURL contains a UIImage? because if it contains a URL to an Image then you need to try my first solution. If it contains a filepath location to an image, then it won't be able to resolve the filepath while it's within that object. Can you tell me exactly what 'EventsImageURL' contains, is it a string?

Comment: @Prasanthi then copy and paste the top bit of code in my answer, and it will work. once you've done that please mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: it is not working for me @Digitalsa 1nt .till showing null value and getting same error